# toJSON() me cambia de gtm-0300 a gtm0000 (zulu)

Tags: javascript, html

tengo un input date, y le ingreso la hora actual de forma predeterminada. Si lo ingreso asi `document.getElementById("fechaGtm").value = fechaHoy;` en el textarea me devuelve:

> Thu Jan 26 2023 11:02:41 GMT-0300 (hora estándar de Argentina)

Pero cuando le agrego toJSON, devuelve GTM0000 (Z = zulu):

> 2023-01-26T14:04:13.506Z

Es decir,  toJSON me cambia la hora de gtm-0300 (local) a gtm0000. No se como solucionarlo.

```js
var fechaHoy = new Date();
document.getElementById("fechaGtmZ").value = fechaHoy;
document.getElementById("fechaGtm-3").value = fechaHoy.toJSON();
```

```html
<body>
<textarea name="" id="fechaGtmZ" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    <textarea name="" id="fechaGtm-3" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>    <label for="inFecha"
      >Entra tu fecha:
      <input
        id="fecha"
        type="date"
        name="inFecha"
        min="0000-01-01"
        required
        pattern="\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}"
    /></label>
    <script src="./app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Revisa esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11382606/javascript-date-tojson-dont-get-the-timezone-offset

Answer (score 1):

## toJSON() y objetos Date (UTC)

La función `toJSON()` convierte un objeto `Date` a una cadena en formato ISO `(yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.sssZ)`, donde Z indica que la hora es en formato UTC (Coordinated Universal Time). Esto significa que si la fecha original estaba en una zona horaria diferente a UTC, se convertirá a la hora UTC. En realidad la fecha siempre está en UTC, sólo que se "presenta" al usuario con el offset correspondiente, pero no nos enredemos con la teoría, vamos a solucionar tu inquietud.

## Formato de fecha personalizado para Date

Si lo que buscas es mantener la hora original presentada al usuario y solo cambiar el formato de la fecha, puedes crear una cadena personalizada utilizando los métodos de acceso de objeto `Date` para obtener los días, meses, años, etc.

De esta manera, se mantiene la hora original en `fechaHoy` y se muestra en el formato deseado. La T y la Z son para adherir al formato ISO, puedes modificar lo que necesites

## Snippet de código de ejemplo

```js
var fechaHoy = new Date();
document.getElementById("fechaGtmZ").value = fechaHoy;
document.getElementById("fechaGtm-3").value = formatearFecha(fechaHoy.toJSON());

function formatearFecha(fechaParam) {
  let fecha = new Date(fechaParam);
  let dia = fecha.getDate();
  let mes = fecha.getMonth() + 1;
  let anio = fecha.getFullYear();
  let hora = fecha.getHours();
  let minutos = fecha.getMinutes();
  let segundos = fecha.getSeconds();
  let fechaPersonalizada = anio + "-" + mes + "-" + dia + "T" + hora + ":" + minutos + ":" + segundos + "Z";
  return fechaPersonalizada;
}
```

```html
<body>
<textarea name="" id="fechaGtmZ" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    <textarea name="" id="fechaGtm-3" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>    <label for="inFecha"
      >Entra tu fecha:
      <input
        id="fecha"
        type="date"
        name="inFecha"
        min="0000-01-01"
        required
        pattern="\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}"
    /></label>
    <script src="./app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

## Otras alternativas

Empleando librerías como [dayjs](https://day.js.org/), [luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/) o [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) se puede manejar los objetos fecha, manipularlos y presentarlos escribiendo menos código.